# Probability of not choosing from a set of replaced values

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

The problem statement is as follows:

There is a set of numbers N numbers $1..N$  (eg: N = $10^6$)

N numbers are chosen uniformly and independently with replacement

---

I would like to be able to answer questions in the following form:

1. What is the probability that at least 1 number is not chosen?
2. What is the probability that *5%* of the N numbers are **not** chosen?
3. What is the probability that greater than *10%* of the N numbers are **not** chosen?

My initial approach is to say, what's the probability that the same number was chosen every single of the N-times, that would be $(\frac{1}{N})^N$ and for an N of 100 that would be the expectation that 99% of the numbers were not chosen.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @probablyme thanks for the tip, I've updated it as best I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll solve this in more generality, since questions like this keep coming up and we need a standard answer to mark them as a duplicate of. So I'll calculate the probabilities for exactly $k$ bins to be empty and for at least $k$ bins to be empty when $m$ balls are distributed uniformly randomly over $n$ bins. Your case is $n=m=N$, with various $k$ given in your three questions.

The probability for $j$ particular bins to be empty is

$$
\left(1-\frac jn\right)^m\;.
$$

Thus, by [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the probability for exactly $k$ bins to be empty is

$$
\sum_{j=k}^n(-1)^{j-k}\binom nj\binom jk\left(1-\frac jn\right)^m\;.
$$

Then the probability for at least $k$ bins to be empty is

\begin{align}
\sum_{l=k}^n\sum_{j=l}^n(-1)^{j-l}\binom nj\binom jl\left(1-\frac jn\right)^m
&=
\sum_{j=k}^n\sum_{l=k}^j(-1)^{j-l}\binom nj\binom jl\left(1-\frac jn\right)^m
\\
&=
\sum_{j=k}^n(-1)^{j-k}\binom nj\binom{j-1}{k-1}\left(1-\frac jn\right)^m\;,\end{align}

the same as the result for exactly $k$ bins but with $\binom{j-1}{k-1}$.

You also wanted the probability for more than $k$ bins to be empty, which is the probability for at least $k$ bins to be empty minus the probability for exactly $k$ bins to be empty:

$$
\sum_{j=k}^n(-1)^{j-k}\binom nj\left(\binom{j-1}{k-1}-\binom jk\right)\left(1-\frac jn\right)^m=\sum_{j=k}^n(-1)^{j-k+1}\binom nj\binom{j-1}k\left(1-\frac jn\right)^m\;,
$$

again of the same form, but now with $\binom{j-1}k$ and with signs reversed.

*Edit in response to the comment*:

If $m$ and $n$ are large, with $m=\alpha n$ (i.e. in your case $\alpha=1$), we have

$$
\left(1-\frac jn\right)^m=\left(1-\frac{\alpha j}m\right)^m\approx\mathrm e^{-\alpha j}\;.
$$

Then

\begin{align}
\sum_{j=k}^n(-1)^{j-k}\binom nj\binom jk\left(1-\frac jn\right)^m
&\approx\sum_{j=k}^n(-1)^{j-k}\binom nj\binom jke^{-\alpha j}
\\
&=\binom nk(\mathrm e^{-\alpha})^k\left(1-\mathrm e^{-\alpha}\right)^{n-k}\;,
\end{align}

a binomial distribution with probability $\mathrm e^{-\alpha}$, as in this case the events of individual bins being empty are approximately independent and the probability for a bin to be empty is roughly $\mathrm e^{-\alpha}$. The probability for at least $k$ bins to be empty (which in this case is approximately the same as the probability for more than $k$ bins to be empty) can then be approximated using one of the known approximations to the binomial distribution, e.g. the [normal approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) by the normal distribution $\mathcal N\left(n\mathrm e^{-\alpha},n\mathrm e^{-\alpha}\left(1-\mathrm e^{-\alpha}\right)\right)$, with

$$
\textsf{Pr}(K\ge k)\approx\frac12\left(1-\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{k-n\mathrm e^{-\alpha}}{\sqrt2n\mathrm e^{-\alpha}\left(1-\mathrm e^{-\alpha}\right)}\right)\right)
$$

Comment: Thank-you for the excellent answer!  I have two follow-ups, The question originally talked about selecting N numbers, say for example if we selected 3N numbers, would that be what "m" is for?  My next question is for very large N is there a away to approximate the calculation? - as computing the binomial coefficient where N is 10^7 is costly even taking into account simplifications etc.

Comment: @Switzy: Distributing $m$ balls over $n$ bins is equivalent to selecting $m$ numbers from $n$ numbers with replacement, so the answer to your first question is "yes". On the second question, I added an approximation to the answer.

Comment: Thats excellent thank-you!  my simulations agree with the approximate you provided with a roughly 0.5% difference.

Comment: @Switzy: I would have expected the error to be less than that for values of the order of $10^7$. Which specific values did you use?